# IONIC - POST JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Tags: json, angular, ionic-framework

When I send a POST request I always get the error: "JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data", but the data will be created in the database

The network tab will show a Status code 201; when I press modify & resend, the request content is a valid JSON

> {"firstName":"t","lastName":"t","password":"t","confirmPassword":"t","year":2018,"month":2,"day":28,"email":"t"}

This is the POST request:

```
let options = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json, */*'})
};

let registerUser = <RegisterUser>({
  firstName: this.model.firstName,
  lastName: this.model.lastName,
  password: this.model.password,
  confirmPassword: this.model.confirmPassword,
  year: parseInt(this.birthday.split('-')[0], 10),
  month: parseInt(this.birthday.split('-')[1], 10),
  day: parseInt(this.birthday.split('-')[2], 10),
  email: this.model.email
});

this.http.post(this.registerUrl, registerUser, options)
        .map((res: Response) => res.json())
        .subscribe(data => {
            console.log("subscribe: " + data);
          },
          error => {
            console.log("error: ", error);
          },
          () => {
            console.log("Complete");
            this.navCtrl.pop();
          });
```

And the stacktrace:

> error:  Object { headers: {…}, status: 201, statusText: "OK", url:
>   "https://music-makers.herokuapp.com/user/register", ok: false, name:
>   "HttpErrorResponse", message: "Http failure during parsing for
>   https://music-makers.herokuapp.com/user/register", error: {…} }
>   register.ts:86:12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it, the backend needs to send a 204 no content response instead a 201. This is a bug in Angular

Or send an empty JSON back, but we didn't test this.

Answer (score 0):

Try remove block:

```
.map((res: Response) => res.json())
```

After change:

```
this.http.post(this.registerUrl, registerUser, options)
    .subscribe(data => {
        console.log("subscribe: " + data);
      },
      error => {
        console.log("error: ", error);
      },
      () => {
        console.log("Complete");
        this.navCtrl.pop();
      });
```

Comment: try add responseType:"text" to options object